# Entity Framework Insert - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: entity-framework, amazon-rds

I'm getting the following error and despite following-up on many 'similar' posts I cannot find find the answer when making insert to 2 tables with a FK using *Entity Framework*.  I think the issue, when looking at the Trace/Log (below) the FK (id) value is 0 (zero).  If I can get that figured out it might solve the problem.

**ERROR: (Obvious what it is saying, but can't figure out how to fix)**

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("xdata"."table_b", CONSTRAINT "f111" FOREIGN KEY ("table_a_id") REFERENCES "table_a" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**MODELS:**

```
public class table_a
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }                
}

public class table_b
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }       
    public int table_a_id { get; set; }       
}
```

**CODE TO INSTANTIATE MODELS AND INSERT:**

```
table_a a = new table_a()
{
     name = "table a name",               
};

table_b b = new table_b()
{
    desc = "table b desc",
    table_a_id = a.id               
};

DataContext.Database.Log = message => Trace.Write(message);
DataContext.TableA.Add(a);
DataContext.TableB.Add(b);

var result = DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

**TRACE:**

SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';

INSERT INTO `table_a`(
`name`) VALUES (
@gp1);
SELECT
`id`
FROM `table_a`
 WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `id`=last_insert_id()
-- @gp1: 'table a name' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 12)
-- Executing at 12/8/2017 7:50:53 PM -07:00
-- Completed in 55 ms with result: EFMySqlDataReader

SET SESSION sql_mode='ANSI';

INSERT INTO `table_b`(
`desc`, 
`table_a_id`) VALUES (
@gp1, 
**0**);
SELECT
`id`
FROM `table_b`
 WHERE  row_count() > 0 AND `id`=last_insert_id()
-- @gp1: 'table b desc' (Type = String, IsNullable = false, Size = 12)
-- Executing at 12/8/2017 7:50:53 PM -07:00
-- Failed in 56 ms with error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ("xdata"."table_b", CONSTRAINT "f111" FOREIGN KEY ("table_a_id") REFERENCES "table_a" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

**DB SCHEMA:**
Edited to remove db schema image (12/8/2017)

```
CREATE TABLE `table_a` 
(
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `table_b` 
(
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
   `table_a_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
   KEY `f111_idx` (`table_a_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `f111` FOREIGN KEY (`table_a_id`) REFERENCES `table_a` (`id`) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: How did you configure the FK relationship between the two entities? At least one of them should have navigation property which I don't see.

Comment: Ivan Stoev...you were exactly right!  No navigation property on my model. If you put an answer down I will mark it answered.